# Desmos domain error?

Tags: real-analysis

Just curious if anyone has an idea why [Desmos would claim](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3rzosdp10o) that $f(0)=0$ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}?

As a note of interest, Geogebra commits the same error but both Symbolab and Wolfram get it right.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It appears to be as you suggest in the title.

Comment: can't see how that's helpful @Gae.S., since the domain cannot include x=0, care to expound a little more?

Comment: I think that it just simplifies the function before drawing it

Comment: @FareedAF yeah it must, but it's weird because it doesn't make a similar mistake for stuff like x/x. In that case it knows x cannot equal 0. Just disappointing to see it doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desmos simplifies functions before evaluating them, to save time. Since desmos is a graphing calculator, the small bit of time saved is not insignificant when dealing with the thousands of points required to represent a curve. While Desmos does check for domain errors in basic cases, many times it does not, and you are observing one of them. Desmos evaluates $\frac{1}{NaN}$ to be 0, so for example, try $\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})}$ and you will get zero as well. Desmos does not however, simplify $\frac{NaN}{NaN}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ so $\frac{x}{x}$ is undefined at $x=0$

Comment: figured as much, but it's really strange, as Desmos usually does a good job with, say, x/x and realizing that x=0 is a domain issue. thanks for confirming my thoughts!

Comment: I updated my answer a bit to explain why examples such as x/x normally work properly, but 1/1/x do not

Comment: Note how Geogebra and Desmos are graphing calculators while Wolfram Alpha is not (it does provide a graph but it is not nearly as interactive as the other two). I do not know how Symbolab works, so I will not comment there.

Comment: thanks @Gabe makes sense.

Comment: That's not quite right, try a = 0/0 then 1/a is still undefined (aka NaN)

Answer (score 0):

They work on the Extended Number Line so
1/0 is ∞ then 1/∞ = 0 again

Note that 0/0 = undefined (NaN) is handled differently

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line